# questions about viewing a model and selecting objects

Tags: 3d-view, selection-tools, scale

I have a few basic questions about Blender that I can not find an answer to and I would appreciate it if someone could help me or point me in the correct direction.

1. My 3d model has a cube with dimensions of 1000x1000x100 and I can not see the whole object in the window at once in perspective view. If I use the wheel on the mouse to zoom out, parts of my cube disappear. I was thinking that I should change my viewport to view a wider area but I can not figure out how to do that.
2. My 3d model actually contains several cubes of around 1000x1000x100. I positioned them by typing numbers into the transform menu in the sidebar. Now if I am in Object Mode and click on one of the cubes or if I click on the object in the outliner, I do not get the crosshairs on the object so that I can move it around with my mouse. I can choose and edit a vertex in Edit Mode, but I can not move or rotate the entire object with my mouse. I have been playing with various settings in the Properties Panel, but if I changed something that I should not have, I can't figure out what I did.
3. The first time I created my model, I tried to resize one of my cubes by typing in values to the transform menu in the sidebar. Then, pressing CTRL-A, Scale to reset the scale back to 1 did not work. I solved the problem by recreating my model in a new file, but I am hoping that there is a better solution.

I have already search online to try to find answers. Probably I am missing something fairly simple, so I would appreciate any advice. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

To fix the view-ability of your object, you can change the camera end-clip distance by pressing <kbd>N</kbd> and finding it under "View".

[image: Clip]

If you are having difficulty changing the transformations of your object, check the Opbect Properties panel and make sure you don't have any Delta Transforms enabled.

[image: Delta]

Comment: Thanks so much for your help.  I adjusted the camera setting, so now I can see the entire model, and I can now see the cursor when I select an object.  I have not yet checked the Delta Transforms to see if that solves my scaling problem, but I will soon.  The Blender screenshots are very helpful.